# Non-linear differential equaton for complex valued function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve the following equation,
$$\dot{q}=i\beta q(t)+\frac{\lambda}{2}q(t)\left[1-|q(t)|^2\right],$$
where $\beta$ & $\lambda$ are real constants. My best idea was to represent the function $q(t)$ as $q(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$, which brings me to the system,
$$\begin{cases} \dot{u}(t)=-\beta v(t)+\lambda u(t)\left[1-u(t)^2-v(t)^2\right]/2, \\ \dot{v}(t)=\beta u(t)+v(t)[1-u(t)^2-v(t)^2]/2\end{cases}.$$
In my opinion this transformation does not give any benifit. Then, I try to just use Wolfram Mathematica to see a solution. Wolfram  gives the following result
$$C-\frac{t}{2}=\int_{1}^{w(t)}d\xi\frac{1}{\xi\left(\lambda|\xi|^2/2-\lambda-2i\omega\right)}.$$
To be honest, I have no idea how I can derive the same result. Can anyone gives some explanation or tips what should I do to solve this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wolfram solution is just the execution of the separation of variables.

One can also get a reduction in complexity from the translation into polar coordinates $q=re^{i\phi}$,
$$
\dot r+ir\dot\phi=iβr+\fracλ2r[1−r^2].
$$
This can again be separated into real and imaginary part to give the equations
\begin{align}
\dot r&=\fracλ2r[1−r^2]\\
\dot\phi&=β
\end{align}
The first is a Bernoulli equation, the second can be easily integrated.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!